# Transporting workout supplements in both cabin and checked luggage

Tags: air-travel, customs-and-immigration, luggage

I have some isolate protein powder, hemp fibers and some pills (**CLA** to be more exact) - all bags opened, *but resealable*. They're part of my current diet and I don't really want to discard them, neither to buy another piece of each when I get to my destination.
I'll have to do multiple flights from Bucharest to Honolulu using 2 reservations and I'll carry two bags - a backpack and a small carry-on:

- the first one, a Ryanair flight from Bucharest to Milan - since I'm allowed to take two cabin bags, I did not purchase a checked bag.
- the second one, a Alitalia flight from Milan to Honolulu - here I'll check the carry-on bag;

Now, my dillemas are:

- can I keep the above mentioned supplements in my carry-on during my first flight (via Ryanair), or it'll not pass security and I'll have to dump them  - in which case I'd better just check-in the bag.
- if I check-in the carry-on bag in which I'll deposit the supplements, can I still have problems with them regarding US Customs?

Comment: For US customs it does not make a difference whether you are bringing your stuff in checked or carry-on luggage. Regarding security for your first flight I do not see a reason why it should not be ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> isolate protein powder, hemp fibers and some pills (CLA to be more exact) - all bags opened, but resealable.

These are all okay with security. The rule of thumb: if it's liquid, flammable, sharp -- you might have a problem, otherwise typically not. Next, we need to look at these things crossing borders -- and for that, it's irrelevant whether in a carry on or checked in.

> Bucharest to Milan

You are within the EU carrying personal amounts. Knock yourself out. You fall under one the four fundamental EU movement freedoms: goods, capital, services, and labour. Goods, in this question.

> Milan to Honolulu

Let's see.

[Can I travel with non-prescription medicines, or other products such as vitamins and health supplements?](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/1217/%7E/traveling-with-non-prescription-medicines%2Fvitamins%2Fhealth-supplements)

> Non-prescription medicines (also known as over-the-counter or OTC medicines), vitamins, herbs, and supplement products fall under the jurisdiction of the Food and Drug Administration (FDA). In general FDA will not object to the personal importation of those products, as long as:
>
> - The traveler is carrying the products in their possession (or in their luggage);
> - The amount being carried is an amount reasonably considered for personal use.

That covers protein power and CLA pills.

Hemp has it's own page.

[Can I import hemp products into the United States?](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/1751/%7E/importing-hemp-products-into-the-u.s.)

> Hemp products such as paper, rope, and clothing (which contain fiber made from the cannabis plant) and animal feed mixtures, soaps, and shampoos (which contain sterilized cannabis seeds or oils extracted from the seeds), etc. may be imported into the United States.

Answer (score -2):

I am pretty sure those are fine since they're supplements and not liquids/hard drugs. In some airports in europe, you may have to put medications in a separate clear plastic bag to go through security but I think that usually only applies to prescription meds.